High precision minimizer
I need a minimizer that works well with high precision. I am currently doing all calculations with mp math to handle the high precision, and am then using a minimizer in scipy where the objective function and the inputs are in mp math format, but ultimatly the resulting minimum values are not in high precision like I need them to be.
Does anyone know of any minimizer that is compatible with mp math that will hold precision.

What kind of problem do you have where you need more than 16 digits of accuracy?

I know that this is possible in Julia, which can be called form Python. See here.

I am doing physics research where the eigen values of the system are extremely small.

Everything I am doing right now is of mp math type and I would like to keep that format for consistancy if possible

Isn't possible to convert your problem to dimensionless problem?

If the underlying problem is genuinely ill-conditioned then nondimensionalization will not save it. Otherwise, this is a relatively easy fix
